# Quotient of rational functions is meromorphic

Tags: complex-analysis

I feel like this should be a very straight forward problem but I am having difficulties with the definition.

I'm trying to prove that $f: \mathbb{C}P^1 \to \mathbb{C}P^1$ given by $f(z) = g(z)/h(z)$ where $g$ and $h$ are polynomials on $\mathbb{C}$ is a meromorphic function.

I understand that to check if it's meromorphic I need to show that it is holomorphic in local coordinates. What I am confused about is as it stands $f$ is not defined on $\mathbb{C}P^1$ but only on $\mathbb{C}$.

It's clear that we should define $f(z_0) = \infty$ if $z_0$ is a zero of $h$ and then in a neighbourhood of $\infty$ in the image the map is locally $h/g$ but then that's holomorphic only away from zeros of $g$? I'm also unsure of how we should define $f(\infty)$.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Doesn't meromorphic mean it is not holomorphic only at isolated set of points, where you have Laurent's expansion?

Comment: My definition of meromorphic is: $f: X \to \mathbb{C}P^1$ where $X$ is a riemann surface is meromorphic if $f$ is not identically $\infty$ and $f$ is holomorphic in local coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't quite as simple as that. Consider the rational function $f(x)=\frac{2x}{x}.$

Instead, assume that $g$ and $h$ are polynomials with no common factor (other than constants). Then you can put $f(z_0)=\infty$ when $g(z_0)=0.$

As for how to treat $f(\infty),$ that depends on the respective degrees of $g$ and $h$. If the degree of $h$ is greater, you should be able to show that $f(z)\to 0$ as $z\to\infty.$ If the degree of $g$ is greater, then instead $f(z)\to\infty$ as $z\to\infty$. Otherwise, $f(z)\to\frac ab,$ where $a,b$ are the respective leading coefficients of $g,h.$

Comment: Okay thanks for your answer. So for case 1 if we assume $deg g > deg h$ then away from infinity in the domain and range the local form is clearly holomorphic. Near infinity in the domain locally the map is then $g(1/z)/h(1/z)$ but how do we tell what chart to use on the range in this case?

Comment: Hmmm...I'm not sure how I would go about that directly, actually. Do you know that finite sums of meromorphic functions are again meromorphic? Do you know that polynomials are meromorphic? Can you show that a rational function is meromorphic if its denominator's degree is greater than its numerator's? If so, then all you should have to do in the case that $\deg(g)\ge\deg(h)$ is to rewrite as $$f(z)=p(z)+\frac{g_1(z)}{h(z)},$$ where $p(z)$ and $g_1(z)$ are polynomials and $\deg(g_1)<\deg(h).$ The rest should follow from the prior results.

Comment: Surely we still have the same issue here showing that $g_1/h$ is holomorphic? Thanks

Comment: Not if you know/can prove the prior results. Since $\deg g_1<\deg h,$ then $g_1/h$ is holomorphic by the previous result.

Comment: Thanks for your help. So yes in that case (showing $g/h$ meromorphic with $\deg g < \deg h$) most points are easy to show it's meromorphic but what about at $f(\infty) = \infty$? Then locally the map is $f_{loc}(z) = \frac{h(1/z)}{g(1/z)}$ and how can we show that's holomorphic?

Comment: Oh it's locally just a taylor series right? Hence no poles?

Comment: In the case that $\deg g<\deg h,$ we have $f(\infty)=0,$ so clearly $f$ doesn't have a pole at $\infty,$ and it suffices that $f$ is meromorphic on $\Bbb C$. Otherwise, we rewrite $f$ as the sum of a polynomial $p$ (which has **at most** one pole, at $\infty$ if anywhere) and a rational function $g_1/h,$ whose denominator has greater degree than its numerator, and so *doesn't* have a pole at $\infty$. Does that make more sense?